# Genymotion and Android Studio error

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I am trying to launch Genymotion. I could launch it before from Android Studio. But Now I can't.

I get this error:

> The exception unknown software exceeption(0xc06d007e) occured in the
>   application at location 0*1fc1871c

Also I can launch Genymotion from virtualbox diectly and it works fine. But not from Android Studio.

Comment: tried to update the AS-plugin?

Comment: Update Android Studio to 1.5.1 and download the newst genymotion plugin